# Como redireccionar a un jsp de otro controller en java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, bootstrap, spring

Tengo el siguiente método en mi controller, el cual me manda a la pagina del login

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String irPaginaLogin(){
  return "/login";
}
```

y este contiene los siguientes campos:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control text-lowercase" id="username" name="username"/>


<input type="text" class="form-control text-lowercase" id="password" name="password"/>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Entrar" onclick=""/>
```

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es que al dar clic en el botón de Entrar me  redireccione a otra pagina "menú", 
esa pagina "menú" la tengo declarada en otro controller, en el siguiente método:

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/menu", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String mostrarMenu(){
  return "/menu";
}
```

Como puedo redireccionar a ese método que muestra el menú ??
o como le puedo agregar una pequeña validación de meter un usuario y contraseña y con ese logearme?

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, parece que estas en un formulario, por lo cual, imagino que deberias enviar la peticion con POST en vez de que con GET. Te lo digo porque veo que tu funcion mostrarMenu usa GET.
Si lo que quieres es mandar los valores del formulario, es decir el usuario y contraseña lo mas facil es que en la definicion de tu formulario ponga  algo asi:

```
form action="/menu"
```

Y cambia en tu funcion para recoger los valores de tu formulario (que para algo los tendras). Algo así como esto:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/menu", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String mostrarMenu(@PathVariable("username") String username,@PathVariable("password") String password)
{
....
}
```